# How to segregate letsencrypt SSL certificate, to hide from a visitor which other sites are being hosted on the same system?

Tags: linux, ssl, debian

I have a system which hosts multiple websites, using letsencrypt for SSL. When browsing any of the sites, one could read the ssl certificate, and see each url of the other sites hosted on the same machine.

It seems all sites are on the same certificate. Is it possible to separate them somehow?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here, but yes you can have one certificate per name. Up to you then to properly manage all of them and renew each of them at appropriate times. However note that things like that is kind of pointless for the goal you are trying to reach: there are many other ways to find all other names hosted on your servers, for example by doing reverse IP or nameservers searches. Don't fall for "security through obscurity" anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have separate ips for the sites as well. Certainly not treating this as a security feature, just want to make it less 'ugly' seeing the whole list of sites on the single certificate.